# Curl to python request - Python

Tags: api, curl, python-requests

I have a curl request with is giving expected output :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token 519dde16245438025cccb526bxxx9f3e8ce88289" --form "user=47" --form "language=HI" --form "audio_file=@/home/rishabh/Desktop/liv/audio_1.wav" --form "transcribe=1" https://dev.liv.ai/liv_speech_api/recordings/
```

But when I do the same using python script I am getting error

Please see the code below :

```
def get_app_session_id():

    headers = {'Authorization' : 'Token 519dde16245438025cccb526bdxxxx3e8ce88289'}
    data = {'user' : '47', 'language' : 'HI', 'transcribe':'1'} 
    files = {'audio_file' : open('audio_1.wav')}
    url = 'https://dev.liv.ai/liv_speech_api/recordings/'
    res = requests.post(url, headers = headers 
    , data = data, files = files)
    return res
```

Let me know how to resolve this issue 
201 means : The request has been fulfilled, resulting in the creation of a new resource